# How to refund money send to an address already used

Tags: blockchain.info

I sent money to a block chain wallet address which had once been used to receive money. Now money is not found in the account. What do I do to recover the money. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> money is not found in the account

If you sent your money to an exchange market wallet then you should ask their support about that issue.

Otherwise, please give us your transaction ID so we can look at it. You may have sent your coins without enough fees or to a wrong address.